# What's the best way to rsync two directories with git repositories?

Tags: networking, rsync, git, remote, synchronization

I have two machines that I use for work. One is the local machine located at my home, and the other is the remote machine located at my office.

I have a "development" folder in which I keep all my work. It contains various folders of LaTeX documents, Python projects, etc. Most of these folders are git repositories themselves. I need to be able to switch between the machines and pick up my development work as and when I require it depending upon my physical presence at home or office.

What's the best way to do rsync of this "development" folder? I did:

```
rsync -zvaP  /media/shihab/development shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development
```

and

```
rsync -zvaP shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development /media/shihab/development
```

but I ended up messing up my file and folder permissions and groups. How do established programmers manage switching between their machines?

Answer (score 0):

`git` can easily do this built-in; use `git+ssh` to treat one machine as the other's remote. I *think* that's all you're asking for.

[Here](https://riptutorial.com/git/example/26674/set-up-ssh-for-git) is one tutorial I found with an internet search.